# Submit Google Play Privacy Policy via Fastlane

Tags: google-play-console, fastlane, fastlane-supply

I am currently trying to bring the automation pipeline for a couple of dozens of app back to speed. They both lack the data privacy and the data safety entries in Google Play so far. I was wondering and investigating how to do that in Fastlane but I can't find any more details in documentation or the repo. Could anybody guide me into a direction how to automate this if possible?

Answer (score 2):

I am in a similar situation.  I have hundreds of apps that needed to be regularly maintained which now requires updates to the Data safety section.

I use fastlane for updating the AAB and play listing information. I looked on fastlane's [discussion](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions) page in their GitHub account and found this article:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/discussions/19851

From this, I learned:

- Fastlane depends on Google Play Store APIs which do not support updating Data safety section.

I submitted a feature request to the Google Play Store Publishing API by submitting it to the [Play Console Help](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/gethelp) page.